# Date and Timestamp serialization by Jackson ObjectMapper

Tags: java, scala, serialization, jackson, fasterxml

Jackson `ObjectMapper` is serializing both `Date` and `Timestamp` as `Long` in **2.9.x** version whereas Date is serialized as `Formatted String` in **2.6.x** and `Timestamp` as `Long` in **2.6.x* version by default.

Example:

```
case class Test(date: java.sql.Date,  tmp: java.sql.Timestamp)
val test = Test(new java.sql.Date(1588892400000L), new Timestamp(1588892400000L))
writeValueAsString(test)
```

```
{"date":"2020-05-08","tmp":1588892400000}//Version 2.6.x 
{"date":1588892400000,"tmp":1588892400000}//Version 2.9.x
```

> But I want to maintain the behavior of **2.6.x** version in **2.9.x** version.

I tried `disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)` but then it is converting both `Date` & `TimeStamp` to `Formatted String` (as below).

```
{"date":"2020-05-08","tmp":"2020-05-07T23:00:00.000+0000"}
```

If I set DateFormatter**, then it converts both in the same format.

```
setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"))`
{"date":"2020-05-08","tmp":"2020-05-08"}
```

**I just treid it but I don't want to set DateFormatter (even if it works) because it will be used for de-serialization too where the input date format is different.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an annotation like this for the `Date` member:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
```

EDIT:

Create a class like this:

```
public class CustomSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Date value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");  
            String s = sdf.format(value);
            gen.writeString(s);
          } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
            gen.writeString("");
          }     
    }
}
```

and use like this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addSerializer(Date.class, new CustomSerializer());
mapper.registerModule(module);
```

Comment: case class in question is an example to show it quickly, actually I am serializing Spark's DataFrame.

Comment: So you need to change only on the ObjectMapper and not on the classes?

Comment: Correct. Customize ObjectMapper configuration for serializing Data from DataFrame.

Comment: In that case the best solution is to create a custom serialize/deserializer for the Date.class. You can refer to this: [link](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/jackson/custom-serializer-deserializer.html).
Tell me if you need further help.

Comment: Thanks Couper, I already have a custom class for object Mapper. And I can consider few points from above article and try it. I hope it will work.

Comment: It seems to be working fine but now it fails during deserialization.And I don't want to set any custom deserialization. Will try to see If I can add default one.

Comment: I implemented only the serializer, not the deserializer, maybe it fails because of that.
You said that you already have a custom class for ObjectMapper, so you can add the custom serializer and deserializer to that class and you should be fine.

Comment: can it be written as Date instead of string