# MyBatis maps Timestamp in milliseconds

Tags: mybatis

How can I map the timestamp result as regular timestamp, like this:

```
"2021-08-17T18:39:52.0000832-12:00"
```

already tried adding the jdbc = jdbc.Type.TIMESTAMP

Comment: `jdbcType = JdbcType.TIMESTAMP, javaType = java.sql.Timestamp.class`
this isn't working, also :(

Answer (score 0):

An amazing solution found here:
[Date and Timestamp serialization by Jackson ObjectMapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61685822/date-and-timestamp-serialization-by-jackson-objectmapper)

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
```